# Inheritance issue with overwriting Notebook - python,tkinter

Tags: python, class, inheritance, tkinter, frame

I cannot solve this issue for couple of hoursfor now. The problem is that I cannot add a proper inheritance method that will overwrite status of tabs in Notebook widget.

if function is called from Solver Class then there is no problem. I want to have the same effect when login function is called from particular Frame/Tab class.

```
class Solver(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook()
        self.add_tab()
        self.notebook.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="test", command=self.loginSuccess)
        self.btn.pack()

    def add_tab(self):
        tab1 = Tab1(self.notebook)
        tab2 = Tab2(self.notebook)


        self.notebook.add(tab1, text="Menu", state="disabled")
        self.notebook.add(tab2, text="Login Page")



    def loginSuccess(self):
        self.notebook.tab(0, state="normal")
        self.notebook.tab(1, state="hidden")

        Root.geometry("380x300")
```

Then I have 2 class which are frames for that notebook's tabs

```
class Tab1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Menu", bg="light blue")
        self.frame1.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        self.lbl = tk.Label(self.frame1, text= "test")
        self.lbl.pack()


# Login
class Tab2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Login", bg="light blue")
        self.frame1.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        [...]
        self.loginButton = tk.Button(self, text="  Login  ", command=self.validateLogin)
        self.loginButton.place(x=300, y=75)

    def validateLogin(self):
        pass
```

And I need that validate Login will do the same as loginSuccess but its called from another class.

Comment: what do you mean by "write a proper inheritance method"? None of the classes you have inherit from any of the other classes. Are you just asking how to call `loginSuccess` from within `Tab2`?

Comment: yes, I've removed all my tries from this code, but i think that major issue here is that this class that inherit from tk.Tk , and tk.Frame can not be mixed. If i want to try like this class Tab1 (Solver, tk.Frame) and then call method from Solver it was not working. Thats why i have pasted raw version so maybe there are solutions to call that modifications from other class.
 self.notebook.tab(0, state="normal")
 self.notebook.tab(1, state="hidden")

Comment: _" think that major issue here is that this class that inherit from tk.Tk , and tk.Frame can not be mixed."_ no, that's not the problem. That is a very common thing to do.

Comment: Do you want to _call_ `loginSuccess` from the tab, or have it _do the same thing_ as `loginSuccess`?

Comment: both ways are fine.

Comment: For your case, you can call `self.master.master.loginSuccess()` in `validateLogin()` because `self.master` is `self.notebook` in `Solver` class and so `self.master.master` is `Solver` class.

Comment: @acw1668. this is perfect thanks :)

Comment: @acw1668 what If i want to call method or variable from another tab?

Comment: It can't tell without code.

Comment: I've figured this out my myself, it took my some time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found some kind of solution. So I've hidden this button from the Solver class and when correct credentials are added to login system , then GUI is extended and button is visible.

Answer (score 0):

One of the cardinal rules of programming is that you need a reference to an object in order to call a method on that object. Thus, if you want to call the `loginSuccess` method of the `Solver` class, you need a reference to the `Solver` object.

One of the simplest ways for you to achieve that is to pass it down to the tab.

First, add `solver` as an argument to the tab `__init__` method:

```
class Tab2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, solver):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.solver = solver
        ...
```

Next, have your function use `self.solver` to call `loginSuccess`:

```
    def validateLogin(self):
        self.solver.loginSuccess()
```

Finally, make sure to pass the `Solver` instance to the tab:

```
class Solver(tk.Tk):
    ...

    def add_tab(self):
        tab1 = Tab1(self.notebook)
        tab2 = Tab2(self.notebook, solver=self)
```